# AJAX returning ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 using Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have two AJAX requests on the same page sending data to a Codeigniter framework.

One sends a form of input fields containing shop opening hours. This functions correctly.

```
$(".hour-field").blur(function(){
$.ajax({
       url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>businesses/updatehours',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: $("#edit-hours").serialize(),
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(data){
           console.log(data)
       }
   });
});
```

The other sends data from a radio input form. This one returns ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200

```
$(".image-selector").click(function(e){
$.ajax({
       url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>businesses/selectimage',
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: $("#select-image").serialize(),
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(data){
           console.log(data)
       }
   });
});
```

I have tried removing the 'dataType' without success.

There is seemingly no difference between the two but one is not working.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code or make a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Setting $config['compress_output'] = FALSE will do the (dirty) job but you should also check if you are passing an empty result object or array to json_encode() function on your controller, or model ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this code in your config file:

```
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
```

Enable gzip compression in php.ini:

```
zlib.output_compression=On
```

Comment: That error has something to do with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php

Comment: I will try this. Is the config file the codeigniter config file? Thanks

Comment: Can the zlib.output_compression=On be done via htaccess per domain?

Comment: I haven't managed to put anything in my .htaccess file, but it seems to be working ok. Perhaps I have some settings within plesk.

Comment: I now have the strange problem that the first click on the radio field doesn't submit the form data with the ajax request so my php script throws an error as the form variable doesn't exist. Subsequent presses do work.

Comment: I realised that I am clicking on images within the radio field's label, therefore I was not sending the correct data with the ajax submission. I have now fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!