# CodeIgniter 3 Error: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 8192

Message: Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated

Filename: core/URI.php

Line Number: 102

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\sin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

codeigniter version 3.1.12

How to fix the error?

Comment: [Creation of dynamic property CI_URI::$config is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122899/creation-of-dynamic-property-ci-uriconfig-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `baseurl` by opening the `application/config/config.php` file with a text editor.

Change:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = ‘http://localhost’;
```