# how to Codeigniter 3 start

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I formatted the computer, then I started Codeigniter 3, but it gave such an error, can you help?
I installed xampp but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122899/creation-of-dynamic-property-ci-uriconfig-is-deprecated/75122968#75122968

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creation of dynamic property CI\_URI::$config is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75122899/creation-of-dynamic-property-ci-uriconfig-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic properties are deprecated in PHP 8.2 and will be removed in PHP 9.

https://medium.com/geekculture/php-what-are-dynamic-properties-2509c6fbccf8

Either upgrade to Code Igniter 4 or downgrade your version of PHP.