# Routes for large CI3 to CI4 upgrade

Tags: codeigniter, upgrade

The nonprofit organization I work for uses Codeigniter for a very large codebase (around 100 controllers and 750 views).  We are planning to upgrade from CI3 to CI4 this year.

Since our codebase is so large, we are looking at some sort of routing configuration that would allow us to have some pages in CI3 and some in CI4 as things are upgraded- So maybe we would have specific routes for pages that have been upgraded to CI4, but then a rule that routes everything else to CI3.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

I'm wondering if anyone else has dealt with this type of migration before, and could share examples of how you dealt with this.

Thank you!

Cross-posted on the Codeigniter forums, but haven't gotten any responses yet...https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=90364

Comment: the first question is: WHY do you want/need to upgrade the existing codebase? what can stay in CI3 and what needs to be CI4? If you can outline those reasons, it might be easier to find an answer. At the moment, I think this question needs more focus or would trend for opinion based  answers...

Comment: And don't forget, CI3 to CI4 is not just an upgrade, it signifies a pretty serious rewrite!

Comment: We are at a university who will upgrade php and eventually CI3 will no longer be supported. Since we are estimating a year for this upgrade we are getting started so we aren't rushing when php is upgraded. We had a scare when the university rolled out php8 and we weren't sure CI3 would be compatible.  We did convert a smaller test site so we are aware of the complexities.

Comment: I'm using CI3 with php 8.3.2. Only had to update some minor things, like the*Creation of dynamic property deprecation warnings*, which you do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009911/2275490.

Comment: Yes but what happens when we upgrade php again...

Comment: in my opinion, I'd just upgrade to CI3.1.13 and update the code errors for php 8.x Then I'd create a testdomain and start to rewrite the code for CI4. You have time. There are no plans for launching php 9.0 yet as by https://benjamincrozat.com/php-90 or https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/wgudj3/php_90_is_comming_2023/?rdt=49994. ANYWAY, the CI-forum gives some hints how to setup a 2 version  site, but I'd say it is a waste of time to make this work 100% (think of sessions, database, cli, cors, cookies, etc...), time which you better use for your re-write.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

My colleague came up with a solution that helps with routing pages between CI3 and CI4 while we migrate pages.  It doesn't solve the session issue either, but we don't have a need for that at this time.

For the solution she implemented, we have CI4 running in a subdirectory within CI3.

CI3 has a controller called CI4redirector, and CI4 has a controller called CI3redirector.  When we finish converting a page to CI4, we can add a route to the CI3 application/config/routes.php.  For example, if we finish the news page our route would look like $route['news']='CI4redirector/ci4/news';  That would redirect the user to CI4.  However, we want links on that CI4 page to direct to CI3 or CI4, depending on if we have converted that page or not.  To achieve this, we use the CI3redirector within CI4 which routes back to CI3.

Here is the code in the CI4redirector controller (located in \application\controllers\CI4redirector.php)

```
class CI4redirector extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
    }
   
    // redirect to CI4 site
    public function ci4($base, $seg=NULL) {
       
        $newPath = base_url() . "CI4/$base";
        if ($seg) $newPath . "/$seg";
        //echo "new path is: $newPath";
       
        redirect($newPath, 'location', 301);
    }
   
}
```

Here is the code in the CI3redirector controller (located in \CI4\app\Controllers\CI3redirector.php)

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CI3redirector extends BaseController {
   
    protected $baseURL_ci3;
   
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
           
        $config = config('App');
        $this->baseURL_ci3 = $config->baseURL_ci3;           
    }
   
    // redirect to CI3 site
    public function ci3($base, $seg=NULL) {
       
        $newPath = $this->baseURL_ci3 . "$base";
        if ($seg) $newPath . "/$seg";
        //echo "new path is: $newPath";
       
        // use php not CI4 redirect for "external" location
        header("location: $newPath");
    }
   
}
```